# Plot a graph from a one row CSV file in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have many csv files that consist of a single row with individual sensor readings separated by a comma. I am attempting to take these readings and plot them as a graph using a panda dataframe, which I will eventually save the image of.

The difficulty I am having is that when I read the csv file, the dataframe consists of a single row with many columns. In turn, I cannot figure out how to plot this properly.

When I print the dataframe this is what I get.

```
df = pd.read_csv(file)
print(df)
```

> Empty DataFrame
> Columns: [-7, -7.1, -7.2, -7.3, -7.4, -7.5, -7.6, -7.7, -7.8, -7.9, -7.10, -7.11, -7.12, -7.13, -7.14, -7.15, -7.16, -6, -6.1, -6.2, -5, -4, -2, 0, 4, 9, 14, 18, 13, 3, -11, -29, -48, -64, -73, -76, -76.1, -74, -71, -68, -67, -66, -65, -65.1, -65.2, -65.3, -65.4, -65.5, -66.1, -65.6, -65.7, -66.2, -66.3, -66.4, -66.5, -66.6, -66.7, -66.8, -66.9, -66.10, -66.11, -67.1, -67.2, -67.3, -67.4, -67.5, -67.6, -67.7, -66.12, -66.13, -66.14, -66.15, -66.16, -66.17, -66.18, -67.8, -71.1, -76.2, -80, -82, -79, -69, -53, -32, -13, 2, 10, 11, 8, 3.1, 0.1, -3, -4.1, -5.1, -6.3, -6.4, -6.5, -7.17, -7.18, -7.19, ...]
> Index: []

When I have attempted to print by column, it does not print correctly. I feel I am just hung up on a simple formatting step, but I cannot seem to find a solution.

```
     for column in df.columns:
     print(df[column])
     plt.figure()
     plt.title(column)
     plt.plot(df[column])
     plt.show()
```

I really appreciate any help or advice!

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that your `.csv` has a single row and looks something like that:

```
-7, -7.1, -7.2, -7.3, -7.4, -7.5, -7.6, -7.7, -7.8, -7.9, -7.10, -7.11, -7.12, -7.13, -7.14, -7.15, -7.16, -6, -6.1, -6.2, -5, -4, -2, 0, 4, 9, 14, 18, 13, 3, -11, -29, -48, -64, -73, -76, -76.1, -74, -71, -68, -67, -66, -65, -65.1, -65.2, -65.3, -65.4, -65.5, -66.1, -65.6, -65.7, -66.2, -66.3, -66.4, -66.5, -66.6, -66.7, -66.8, -66.9, -66.10, -66.11, -67.1, -67.2, -67.3, -67.4, -67.5, -67.6, -67.7, -66.12, -66.13, -66.14, -66.15, -66.16, -66.17, -66.18, -67.8, -71.1, -76.2, -80, -82, -79, -69, -53, -32, -13, 2, 10, 11, 8, 3.1, 0.1, -3, -4.1, -5.1, -6.3, -6.4, -6.5, -7.17, -7.18, -7.19
```

If you really want to use pandas for this task, you should read it using parameter `header=None` - since you don't have any header.

```py
df = pd.read_csv(file, header=None).T
```

`.T` transpose the dataframe (so it would have single column instead of single row).

And from now on you can use every visualisation package, for example  pandas built-in methods:

```py
df.plot()
```

[image]